# Implement a partial update of a complex JPA entity using an older version of the entity class

Tags: rest, jpa, jax-rs, forward-compatibility

I am having a conceptual problem on which I hope someone might have an answer.

## What do I already have?

I have a RESTful service which offers CRUD-like operations for a single type of entity. The entity (lets call it **order**) is represented as JSON using Jackson. The Jackson annotations are directly attached to the entity classes, there is no distinct data transport layer. The entity class contains quite a number of attributes, one-to-one and one-to-many relations.

Technologically, it is based on Wildfly 10, JAX-RS 2.0 and JPA 2.1 (using Hibernate 5).

Supported operations right now are:

- GET `orders/123` *reads* the entity by using `EntityManager.find`
- PUT `orders/123` *creates* or *replaces* the entity by using `EntityManager.persist` or `EntityManager.merge`

### Code sample

A simplified version of the entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Order {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "order_id", sequenceName = "order_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="order_id")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Version
    private long version;

    @Column(name = "correlation_id", unique = true)
    private long correlationId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private SubOrder subOrder;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "suborder")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class SubOrder {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "suborder_id", sequenceName = "suborder_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="suborder_id")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Version
    private long version;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "suborder_order_FK1"))
    @JsonBackReference
    private Order order;

    @Column(name = "field1", length = CommonConstants.LENGTH_4, nullable = true)
    private String field1;
}
```

A JSON representation would look like this:

```
{
  "id": 6000000197444,
  "version": 358,
  "correlationId": 4711,
  "suborder": {
    "id": 1000000005025,
    "version": 40,
    "field1": "value"
  }
}
```

## What do I want to do?

Now, I want to add a field **field2** to the entity `Order`. The service has multiple clients - **Client1** and **Client2**.

**Client1** performs an update of the entity and gives the new field the value *newValue*:

```
{
  "id": 6000000197444,
  "version": 358,
  "correlationId": 4711,
  "field2": "newValue",
  "suborder": {
    "id": 1000000005025,
    "version": 40,
    "field1": "value"
  }
}
```

**Client2** is not interested in the new field. Therefore, no new version of **Client2** is developed. Now, it wants to change the value of `field1` to the value *anotherNewValue*. As it does not know of the new field `field2`, it PUTs the following JSON to the service:

```
{
  "id": 6000000197444,
  "version": 358,
  "correlationId": 4711,
  "suborder": {
    "id": 1000000005025,
    "version": 40,
    "field1": "newValue"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, **Client1** decides to remove the value from `field2` once again. Because the value is now empty and, according to the Jackson annotations, empty values are not included, the following JSON is being PUT:

```
{
  "id": 6000000197444,
  "version": 358,
  "correlationId": 4711,
  "suborder": {
    "id": 1000000005025,
    "version": 40,
    "field1": "newValue"
  }
}
```

## What is the problem?

This solution provides a serious problem:
**A client using an older representation of the entity will accidentially remove fields that are unknown to it.**

So basically it will break **forward compatibility** which is a huge issue for me!

I have some possible solutions, but each of it has serious shortcomings:

1. *Deploy a new version of the service for each evolution of the entity*: Easy and will work for sure, but results in a large number of versions that have to be maintained at the same time.
2. *Use a specific media type for each version*: This would allow the client to specifiy which version of the entity it refers to. However, I would need to **manually** merge the differences between the received entity (taking into account which fields are present in which version) and the one in the database.
3. *PATCH with partial updates*: I could split the problem in two problems:

   - Create the patch (client): I would have to manually compare the entity before and after the modification.
   - Apply the patch (server): I would have to select the entity from the database and manually apply the patch.

## Where I would like your help

I think that is a pretty common problem so I hope some of you has already done something like this. I have to specific questions:
1. Does anyone know of a Java library that allows to create and apply patches on arbirtary object trees (as required in solutions 2 und 3)?
2. Does anyone have a simpler solution?

**Sorry that the text became so long, but I wanted to included all relevant details. Thank you very much for your time!**

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a good solution to this?